# Can I solve limit of natural log without using L'Hospital Rule

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I want to find the following limit: $$\lim_{x\to 2} \dfrac{\ln(x+3)-\ln(5)}{(x-2)}$$
but can we find the limit without using L'Hospitals Rule?
It is an indeterminate form but I do not know how to rewrite it.

Answer (score 8):

We have
$$\lim_{x \to 2} \dfrac{\ln(x+3)-\ln(5)}{x-2} = \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{\ln(5+h)-\ln(5)}{h} = \lim_{h \to0} \dfrac{\ln(1+h/5)}h = \dfrac15$$
where we made use of the fact that $\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{\ln(1+y)}y=1$.

Comment: For the sake of the OP, the lmit that is used here is the definition of the derivative of $\ln(x)$ at $x=1$

Comment: Alternatively, that last limit can be derived solely from the fact that $\ln(1+x)\le x$ for all $x$. (Substituting in $u$ such that $1+x=\frac1{1+u}$, rearranging, and changing variable names, tells us that $\frac x{1+x}\le\ln(1+x)$. Thus, we have $\frac x{1+x}\le\ln(1+x)\le x$, and dividing by $x$ — noting that the inequalities will flip if $x$ is negative — and using the squeeze theorem gives us your limit.)

Comment: @Joel It is actually the other way around, the fact that the derivative of $\ln(x) = \dfrac1x$ is a consequence of the fact that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(1+x)}x  = 1$.

Comment: @columbus8myhw This is a nice way to derive. Though, how do you show that $\ln(1+x) \leq x$ without the limit?

Comment: @user17762 It's equivalent to $e^x\ge x+1$, which I like to take as the definition of $e$. (It's a definition powerful enough to prove that $\ln2=1-\frac12+\frac13-\dotsb$, without calculus. Of course, you need to show that such a number exists, but it's intuitively obvious after playing around with [a graphing calculator](http://www.desmos.com) for a bit.)

Comment: @user17762 I suppose it could be thought of that way. Generally, I think of the derivative of $\ln(x)$ coming from the inverse formula for derivatives, and using $e^{x}$.

Answer (score 7):

One way is to realize that by defintion this limit is the derivative of the function $f(x)=\ln(x+3)$ at $x=2$. Assuming that you made a typo for $x \to 3$.

Answer (score 6):

Bernoulli's Inequality says that for $n\ge1$ and $x\ge-n$,
$$
1+x\le\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\tag{1}
$$
Thus, for all $x$, we have
$$
1+x\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n=e^x\tag{2}
$$
Substituting $x\mapsto-\frac{x}{1+x}$ gives $\frac1{1+x}\le e^{-\frac{x}{1+x}}$, which implies $e^{\frac{x}{1+x}}\le1+x$.

Thus, for $x\gt-1$,
$$
\frac{x}{1+x}\le\log(1+x)\le x\tag{3}
$$
Dividing by $x$ yields, for $x\gtrless0$,
$$
\frac1{1+x}\lessgtr\frac{\log(1+x)}x\lessgtr1\tag{4}
$$
Thus, by the Squeeze Theorem,
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log(1+x)}x=1\tag{5}
$$

---

Thus, because $\frac{x-2}5\to0$ as $x\to2$,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to2}\frac{\log(x+3)-\log(5)}{x-2}
&=\frac15\lim_{x\to2}\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{x-2}{5}\right)}{\frac{x-2}5}\\
&=\frac15\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Ah, very nice proof using that. :) I actually use another way using limit definition of $e$ in by shifting the $1/x$ inside the $log$ as power of $(1+x)$

Comment: Note that, when dividing by $x$, the inequalities flip, but it ends up not mattering.

Comment: @columbus8myhw: when $x\lt0$, you are correct on both counts. There should be a better notation for "between" that could be used here.

Comment: @columbus8myhw: I have used `\gtrless` and `\lessgtr` to make things a bit better.